# how can i find the name value in laravel in this way?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-blade

```
  @for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++)
      <tr>
         <td><input type="text" name="{{$users[$i]->id}}" value="{{$users[$i]->name}}" class="form-control" disabled ></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="{{'breakfast'.$i}}" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="{{'lunch'.$i}}" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="{{'dinner'.$i}}" class="form-control" value="0"></td>
       </tr>
  @endfor
```

expected names value = breakfast0, breakfast1 etc. and lunch0, lunch1 etc.

Comment: You want to read all values in the controller when posted? Instead of posting form fields with a dynamic name, you can post them as an array. `name="breakfast[]"`. the first field is disabled and will not be posted

Comment: "The first field is disabled and will not be posted". I cannot permit editing by the user, how can i do it?

Comment: Also note that if you don't want the user to be able to edit a field, this should be handled in your backend code. A disabled input can be changed in the developer tools of the browser, and so be submitted anyway.